# Is there a non-religious word for someone who takes suffering onto themselves for a particular cause?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word like *martyr*, but without any religious implications.

Also, the idea is that the person doesn't kill themselves, but instead just takes on a great deal of suffering for the good of the cause.

Comment: Heh! [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/martyr) doesn't really help with non-religious: *scapegoat, offering, saint.* And that's it.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I did some cursory searches before I posted this question. :)

Comment: It's a good idea to post what you've done and found, so that others don't repeat that work unnecessarily (not that I begrudge a single search and a comment).

Comment: The word is _martyr_, and it need have no religious connotation. It's just that the most famous martyrs are religious ones.

Comment: @John Lawler: I'll concede that Justin Martyr was a martyr.

Comment: I totally agree with John, it's the best word and it's used in non-religious contexts more than enough not to be put off by that connection.

Comment: ...Yes. If OP wants a word with no religious connotations, I'd say he's on a loser. I'm using the broader sense of 'connotation' (producing, or capable of producing, a secondary semantic impression in at least some people). He'll just have to bite the bullet. _Martyr_ is often used as an opaque metaphor (or is it a dead one?) for a sufferer for a cause rather than the literal life-giver.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is predicated on the false presumption that ***martyr*** always has religious implications and/or always implies that the "martyr" actually *dies* for his cause.

Comment: ... [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyr) has: A martyr (Greek: μάρτυς, mártys, "witness"; stem μάρτυρ-, mártyr-) is somebody who suffers persecution and death for advocating, renouncing, refusing to renounce, and/or refusing to advocate a belief or cause, usually a religious one. >> I'd say this justifies the statement " 'martyr' has religious connotations'. This doesn't demand that it must be used solely in the religious domain, of course.

Comment: Maybe "Risk-taker"

Comment: I think this question is on-topic but an area of ambiguity may be this: ***why*** is the person working for the cause, suffering?  Is it from taking on a lion's share of the work (as is the case in many causes - particularly non-profit causes), or is the suffering meant to elicit pity and attention?  What's the motive behind the suffering?

Comment: It's not so much the lion's share of the work, as the onerous, tedious part of the work. The parts of the work nobody else wants to touch, because they are onerous.

Comment: Do you mean masochists ?

Answer (score 1):

Someone who works extremely hard for a good cause can be described with these nouns, adjectives and idioms:

> - ***Tireless***
> - ***self-sacrificing***
> - a real ***trouper***
> - ***dedicated to the cause***

Comment: 'self-sacrificing' and 'trooper' seem right to me, but the other two, though they may be characteristics that a martyr has, are not necessary or sufficient to make that person a martyr

Comment: Of course, 'trooper' should be 'trouper'. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trouper

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, **diehard** has this sense:

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/diehard)

> noun  [often as modifier]
>
> A person who strongly opposes change or who continues to support
>   something in spite of opposition.

[tidied]

Though the word doesn't require that the referent self-immolates, I think it conveys (by its morphemes) a sense of great trials and hence almost certainly sufferings.

Answer (score -1):

The word martyr is a Greek word that means "witness." A martyr was a witness to an event or a witness called to testify in a legal matter.

What you seek is a definition to the connotation of martyr. Which has different meanings based upon one's social, religious or personal belief systems.

Because of the inherent nature of language, whatever your meaning may not be what others understand you to mean.